# My toilet won't flush when it's windy

Tags: toilet, septic-tanks

I have a septic tank. When it's windy it won't flush. The bowl fills up and will slowly go down, but no complete flush.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where are you located? Does the water move when it's windy and you aren't flushing? Is your system properly vented?

Comment: Both toilet vents are about 10 feet apart. The water in the bowl moves when it's windy. Both toilets won't flush. Would a vent cap help with the wind blowing over the vents?

Comment: Not vent cap.?That sounds like I'm closing the pipe. ?? Something to go on top of the vent pipe. To help with the high winds

Answer (score 1):

### It sounds like you have inadequate venting for your toilet.

In theory, all drains have a trap to prevent sewer gasses from entering your house. In order to drain properly, however, and prevent a trap from fully siphoning every time you drain the fixture (excluding how the toilet is special because I don't think it's relevant here), it needs ventilation.

This picture shows where vents are necessary.

[image: drain waste system]

The vent prevents the rushing water from pulling a vacuum and making it harder to flush or drain the fixture.

Now, you mention this is only a problem when it's windy out. Air moving over a pipe can create a lower static pressure in the pipe, and the vents often go out through the roof.

This may make it harder to flush since less air pressure is available to prevent the draining water from pulling the vacuum I mentioned before, so it will appear to back up slightly.

I haven't tried this before, but putting an angled piece of pipe on top of your roof vent may help solve the problem.

This is what I mean:

[image: angled extension]

The red piece going over the existing vent *could* help prevent the wind from lowering the pressure in the pipe as much.

Comment: Angled vent is good idea, more so if the wind tends to come from a specific direction and the vent is back-to the prevailing wind.

Comment: As long as it isn't flat, it will help prevent the loss of pressure, but if possible, using the backside as a shield will help, as you say @DanielGriscom